# How to solve TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined in react js when in use of useMutation react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am new to React, I am creating a register page where users can register for a new account.  Once the user inserts their info of email, full name, username, and password, once click register it sent via Axios POST request to the server, for sending the user data via Axios I used react hook of useMutation. I follow the example from the react query doc, but I got an error of TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined in line number 57. Plz, help me with this.
Thank you in advance.
`code`
[TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQFkf.png)

```js
 const [data, setData] = useState({
    email: "",
    fullname: "",
    username: "",
    password: "",
  });
    const mutation = useMutation(newRegister => axios.post("/Account/Register",{newRegister}),
    { onSuccess: () => {        
    setData('')
  },
});

  
  function submit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        mutation.mutate({
          email:data.email,
          fullname:data.fullname,
          username:data.username,
          password:data.password})
        .then((res) => {
        res.data=setLoading(false);
        setMessage({
          data: "Registered successfully.",
          type: "alert-success",
        });
          setTimeout(() => {
            history.push("/login");
          }, 3000);
      }) 
      .catch((err) =>{
      alert(`Registered  failed! ${err.message}.`);
    
      return err.message;
      
      })
      
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    const newdata = { ...data };
    newdata[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
    setData(newdata);
  }
```

Comment: `useMutation` is not a default react hook. It might make sense to identify the library you have that from and mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `useMutation` function return type is not a `Promise` hence you won't be able to call `then` (unknown) method.

Since you are trying to perform an action upon mutation success, you should use the afforded `onSuccess` callback (that you are ignoring):

```
const mutation = useMutation(
  newRegister => axios.post("/Account/Register", {newRegister}),
  { onSuccess: (data) => {        
      setData('');
      res.data = setLoading(false);
      setMessage({
        data: "Registered successfully.",
        type: "alert-success",
      });
      setTimeout(() => {
        history.push("/login");
      }, 3000);
    },
    onError(error) => {
      alert(`Registered  failed! ${error}.`);
    }
  });

function submit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    mutation.mutate({
      email:data.email,
      fullname:data.fullname,
      username:data.username,
      password:data.password
    })
}
```